# Read out tensorboard hparams programatically

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard, hyperparameters

after running a hyperparameter search with PyTorch and visualizing the results in Tensorboard, I want to read out the hyperparameters from Tensorboard programatically.

My folder structure is

- all_runs

  - run1

    - Loss_trainingloss
    - 1634168941.9091413 (or some other timestamp)
      events.out.tfevents.1634168941
    - events.out.tfevents.1634135651
  - run2
  - run3

and I can easily read tensorboard time-series like e.g. the loss curve with code like this:

```
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator

def read_eventfile(filepath, tag):
    event_accumulator = EventAccumulator(filepath)
        event_accumulator.Reload()

        events = event_accumulator.Scalars(tag)

        y = [x.value for x in events]

        return y

train_loss_curve = read_eventfile(path_to_event_folder, "Loss_trainingloss")
```

However I struggle to find an access to the hparams of each run, which are correctly displayed in tensorboard. Anybody knows how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just finished a tool called [tbparse](https://github.com/j3soon/tbparse) to read the `hparams` events easily as follows:

```
from tbparse import SummaryReader
log_dir = "<PATH_TO_EVENT_FILE_OR_DIRECTORY>"
reader = SummaryReader(log_dir)
hp = reader.hparams
print(hp)
```

See [the documentation](https://tbparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/parsing-hparams.html) for more usages.

Comment: + 1 for this tool, it's great stuff. Though I did find that the init function gets stuck on Reload if log_dir contains multiple event files.

Comment: @nadlr tbparse requires more time to load if there are multiple event files. Feel free to [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/j3soon/tbparse/issues) if you cannot resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Too bad that there isn't a nice public api, but this seems to work

```py
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams.plugin_data_pb2 import HParamsPluginData

path_str = "path/to/your/events.out.tfevents.xyz"
ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(path_str, 
                                        size_guidance={'tensors': 0} 
                                        )
ea.Reload()

data = ea._plugin_to_tag_to_content["hparams"]["_hparams_/session_start_info"]
hparam_data = HParamsPluginData.FromString(data).session_start_info.hparams
hparam_dict = {key: hparam_data[key].ListFields()[0][1] for key in hparam_data.keys()}
```